# How to access PostgreSQL RETURNING value in Spring Boot DAO?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, dao

I want to return the auto-generated id of entity. PostgeSQL is able to automaticaly selects certain column via `RETURNING`, but I have a hard time trying to find how to retrieve this value in Spring Boot.
I would want something like:

```
public int createUser(User user) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, surname) VALUES (?,?) RETURNING id";
    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql,
            user.getName(),
            user.getSurname(),
            resultSet -> resultSet.getInt("id")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's straightforward in Hibernate, then whether you use a Repository class or an EntityManager, the `save` method returns the saved entity, so you can just do:

```
int id = userRepository.save(user).getId();
```

Or is there a reason you want to persist it the way you do?

Comment: Yes, unfortunatelly i am allowed to only use DAO

Comment: It's not a question of what you persist, it's a question of how. But if you insist on this oldschool way, you can always get the id in the sql way: `"SELECT * FROM user WHERE name="+user.getName()+" AND surname="+user.getSurname()`

Comment: It wouldn't work properly in database without `UNIQUE` constraint